# Geometry of the complex Gauge group

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, moduli-spaces, complex-manifolds, gauge-theory

Let $E\rightarrow X$ be holomorphic vector bundle on a complex manifold $X$. Denote by $\mathcal{G}=\Gamma(Aut(E))$ the group of complex smooth automorphisms of $E$.

Is there a way to endow $\mathcal{G}$ with a structure of complex infinite dimensional manifold?

Possibility: Taking a base point $\bar{\partial}_E$ we make $\mathcal{G}$ act by conjugation so that we obtain an orbit $\mathcal{G}\cdot \bar{\partial}_E\subset Dol(E)$ where $Dol(E)$ denote the space of holomorphic structures of $E$. We know that $Dol(E)$ is an affine space modeled over $\Omega^{0,1}(X,End(E))$ which is itself a complex vector space, so that $Dol(E)$ is a complex manifold.

Can we use such a map $\mathcal{G}\rightarrow Dol(E)$ to "import" a complex structure on $\mathcal{G}$ or on a quotient of $\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: By "complex smooth automorphisms" do you mean smooth section of the bundle of fiberwise complex automorphisms?
Since this is a group, it suffices to give a smooth structure on a neighborhood of 1, one under which action of a single element "close to 1" would be smooth.
And a neighborhood of 1 is covered by adding "small" smooth section of $\mathrm{End}(E)$.
What "close to 1" and "small" mean depends on the topology of $\mathcal{G}$. Do you want a specific topology?